# Regex for visible text, not HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

If i had a string:

```
hey <a href="#user">user</a>, what are you doing?
```

How, with regex could I say: look for `user`, but *not* inside of `<` or `>` characters? So the match would grab the user between the `<a></a>` but not the one inside of the `href`

I'd like this to work for any tag, so it wont matter what tags.

**== Update ==**

Why i can't use `.text()` or innerText is because this is being used to highlight results much like the native cmd/ctrl+f functionality in browsers and I dont want to lose formatting. For example, if i search for `strong` here:

```
Some <strong>strong</strong> text.
```

If i use `.text()` itll return "Some strong text" and then I'll wrap `strong` with a `<span>` which has a class for styling, but now when I go back and try to insert this into the DOM it'll be missing the `<strong>` tags.

Comment: interesting. what are you doing it for?

Comment: How are you getting this text? innerHTML? You could try simply getting the text.

Comment: @Benny for a sort of JS search. I want to search what is visible to the user with like `.highlight('user')`

Comment: @bazmegakapa It's going to be a jQuery plugin, but i'd like to know the regex when I import this same concept into a JS library. It's using `$('someelement').html()` in getting the HTML

Comment: @Oscar Great, then use `.text()` and the big problem is solved. Parsing HTML with regex only promises problems for you.

Comment: @OscarGodson: Are you also setting the HTML again this way? You will loose event handlers bound to elements if you do it that way.

Comment: @Bazmegakapa see my updated post, that wont work :(

Comment: @Felix crap... forgot about that, any ideas? Maybe I need to absolute position these highlights instead?

Comment: Oh... I think I might have missed some point. Do you actually want  to search for some text inside a **string** or in the DOM? I assumed the latter.

Comment: Nope http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @SamGreenhalgh If you have a solution let me know. This is 2 years old, but I'm sure others could benefit from any solution, regex or not, rather than that thread.

Comment: @OscarGodson I'm afraid, two years on, that answer is still quite relevant, as the the 4458 upvotes would suggest. This might explain more http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html . I'd consider using the DOM to find nodes that match what you're looking for and then wrap them in an element using DOM manipulation methods.

Answer (score 8):

If you plan to replace the HTML using `html()` again then you will loose all event handlers that might be bound to inner elements and their `data` (as I said in my comment).

Whenever you set the content of an element as HTML string, you are creating new elements.

It might be better to recursively apply this function to every **text node** only. Something like:

```
$.fn.highlight = function(word) {
    var pattern = new RegExp(word, 'g'),
        repl = '<span class="high">' + word + '</span>';

    this.each(function() {
        $(this).contents().each(function() {
            if(this.nodeType === 3 && pattern.test(this.nodeValue)) {
                $(this).replaceWith(this.nodeValue.replace(pattern, repl));
            }
            else if(!$(this).hasClass('high')) {
                $(this).highlight(word);
            }
        });
    });
    return this;
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/Zk7Mt/)

It could very well be that this is not very efficient though.

Comment: Do you think searching for the word, wrapping it in a "temp" span, getting the x,y of that span, then creating an element on top of that would be more efficient?

Comment: @OscarGodson: No, because you are effectively doing the same (wrapping the word in some tag) *plus* some extra work. Inspecting every text node (recursively) is what takes time. Depending on the selector it can also be that you visit nodes several times. I suggest you test it in various scenarios and try to improve upon it.

Answer (score 2):

To emulate Ctrl-F (which I assume is what you're doing), you can use [`window.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.find) for Firefox, Chrome, and Safari and [`TextRange.findText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536422%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for IE.

You should use a feature detect to choose which method you use:

```
function highlightText(str) {
    if (window.find)
        window.find(str);
    else if (window.TextRange && window.TextRange.prototype.findText) {
        var bodyRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        bodyRange.findText(str);
        bodyRange.select();
    }
}
```

Then, after you the text is selected, you can style the selection with CSS using the [`::selection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/%3a%3aselection) selector.

**Edit:** To search within a certain DOM object, you could use a roundabout method: use `window.find` and see whether the selection is in a certain element. (Perhaps say `s = window.getSelection().anchorNode` and compare `s.parentNode == obj`, `s.parentNode.parentNode == obj`, etc.). If it's not in the correct element, repeat the process. IE is a lot easier: instead of `document.body.createTextRange()`, you can use `obj.createTextRange()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("body > *").each(function (index, element) {

  var parts = $(element).text().split("needle");
  if (parts.length > 1)
    $(element).html(parts.join('<span class="highlight">needle</span>'));
});
```

[jsbin demo](http://jsbin.com/ayati5/7/edit)

at this point it's evolving to be more and more like Felix's, so I think he's got the winner

---

original:

If you're doing this in javascript, you *already* have a handy parsed version of the web page in the DOM.

```
// gives "user"
alert(document.getElementById('user').innerHTML);
```

or with jQuery you can do lots of nice shortcuts:

```
alert($('#user').html()); // same as above

$("a").each(function (index, element) {
    alert(element.innerHTML); // shows label text of every link in page
});
```

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @oscar - updated. Guess it wanted a global selector to get things started, but now working as (I think) you wanted

Comment: Wow, simple, and close, not quite there (notice the three needle words): http://jsbin.com/ayati5/5/edit

Comment: This would wrap the whole element `<div> Search word somewhere here</div>` in a `span` tag. I think only single words should be wrapped.

Comment: @Oscar - are you meaning that you also want to highlight 'needles'?

Comment: oops: http://jsbin.com/ayati5/6 (even so, it should highlight needle but not highlight the s)

Comment: Here is another example that shows that it does not work: http://jsbin.com/ayati5/8/edit#preview (what I mentioned in my previous comment).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/[(<.+>)(^<)]*user[(^>)(<.*>)]/
```

It means:

Before the keyword, you can have as many `<...>` or `non-<`.

Samewise after it.

**EDIT:**

The correct one would be:

```
/((<.+>)|(^<))*user((^>)|(<.*>))*/
```

Comment: Hmm, seems to break it. Look at the generated HTML: http://jsbin.com/ayati5/3/edit

Comment: Cool, think its working, but how can I get that in a `.replace()` with `$N` so I could do something like: `str.replace(/((<.+>)|(^<))*user((^>)|(<.*>))*/g,'<span class="highlight">$1</span>')`

Answer (score 0):

I like regexes, but because tags can be nested, you will have to use a parser. I recommend http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ it is really powerful and easy to use. If you have wellformed xhtml you can also use SimpleXML from php.

edit: Didn't see the javascript tag.

Comment: Doesnt matter if tags are nested. <div>a<div>b<div>c</div></div></div> wouldn't matter because proper regex would simply look for any string thats NOT between <*>

Comment: @Oscar - and what if the markup is <div class="> my text">my text</div> ?

Comment: @Oscar: This could result in "a<div>b<div>c</div></div>". Or look into that and you get "b<div>c</div>". I just thought that was not what you wanted. @Alohci: You have to use entities in this case. e.g &lt; instead of <.

Comment: @Alochi I don't expect my script, nor would I expect anyone else's scripts to understand malformed HTML. In the 1 in a million edge cases a user tries to name a class an invalid class name I don't expect my script to work.

Comment: that'd be an issue if I wasn't looking globally i think, but basically each time I see `<*>` remove it from the search (not the DOM, just the search)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what works, I tried it on your JS Bin:

```
var s = 'hey <a href="#user">user</a>, what are you doing?';
s = s.replace(/(<[^>]*)user([^<]>)/g,'$1NEVER_WRITE_THAT_ANYWHERE_ELSE$2');
s = s.replace(/user/g,'Mr Smith');
s = s.replace(/NEVER_WRITE_THAT_ANYWHERE_ELSE/g,'user');
document.body.innerHTML = s;
```

It may be a tiny little bit complicated, but it works!

Explanation:

- You replace "user" that **is** in the tag (which is easy to find) with a random string of your choice that you must never use again... ever. A good use would be to replace it with its hashcode (md5, sha-1, ...)
- Replace every remaining occurence of "user" with the text you want.
- Replace back your unique string with "user".

Answer (score -1):

this code will strip all tags from sting

```
var s = 'hey <a href="#user">user</a>, what are you doing?';
s = s.replace(/<[^<>]+>/g,'');
```

Comment: [No. It's wont.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-rege)

Comment: @Dim_K : you did. In your example, the value of `s` will be `'hey user, what are you doing?`.

Comment: @Dim - that link is a whole compilation of examples

Comment: @Oltarus yes it is right. Regexp save only visible text. What is wrong?

Comment: @Dim_K you didn't isolate `user`... You stripped HTML.

Comment: @Oltarus title is about visible text. i think `user` just explanation

Comment: @Dim_K Nope, I think @Oscar Godson is looking for some precise text which is in the string but **not** in the HTML. not for "Anything that is non-HTML".

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I don't want to strip HTML, i want a result from a string, but don't search HTML tags. So, with your current code, if you had the right regex, it'd return `"hey <a href="#user"></a>, what are you doing?"`

Comment: But ill replace it with like "`<span class="result">$1</span>`" which would make the resulting HTML `hey <a href="#user"><span class="result">user</span></a>, what are you doing?` -- Does that make more sense?